# Sintflut - Etymologie?

Tags: etymology

Ich habe so allerhand Erklärungen gehört. Zusammenhang 
mit Sünde, was allerdings nicht überzeugt. Sogar Zusammenhang mit Sund (Name einer Meerenge) habe ich gehört. Aber es müßte eigentlich möglich sein, hier etwas Brauchbares zu finden. DWDS versucht es, die Deutungen dort laufen letztlich auf eine Wortfamilie wie in lat. semper (immer) hinaus. Aber die Sintflut der Bibel dauert nicht immer an. Wenn ich mich recht erinnere, stieg das Wasser 40 Tage lang an, bis die Bergspitzen mit Wasser bedeckt waren und es soll etwa ein Jahr gedauert haben, bis das Land wieder trocken war. Aber ein solcher Zeitraum ist nicht immer.
http://www.dwds.de/?qu=sintflut

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sintflut

Meine persönliche Meinung ist, dass Sint- in Sintflut mit lateinisch centum hundert zusammen hängt und einfach Jahrhundertflut bedeutet, also die gŕößte Flut eines Jahrhunderts. Natürlich kann ein solches Wort seine Bedeutung erweitern zu größte Flut überhaupt, so wie das Wort in der Bibel gebraucht wird.

Ein Lautwandel von c zu s ist nicht das Normale. Der reguläre Lautwandel von lateinisch c ist zu k/h im Deutschen, wie bei L caput - D Kopf / Haupt.
Ich nehme bei cent-um zu Sint- einen Sonderfall an, dessen Gründe man erst ermitteln müßte. Es gibt aber solche Sonderfälle wie bei die Sichel, Zusammenhang mit lat.falcicula, Diminutivform von L falx/falcis. (fal)cicula und die Sichel stehen in Zusammenhang.

Comment: Wann wurde das Wort denn erstmalig verwendet? In Luthers Bibelübersetzung? Sprach man denn damals von Jahrhundert~...? Kommt mir doch reichlich modern vor. Was ist mit dem ewigen Eis - das gibt es auch noch nicht ewig und wird es nicht ewig geben?

Comment: Kannst du in DWDS nachlesen. sintfluot, ahd, 9. Jhd.  Wenn dir "Immerflut" besser gefällt als Erklärung steht es dir frei,  Sintflut so zu erklären.

Comment: Lateinisch cent-um hundert ist nicht "reichlich modern", sondern etwa 2000 Jahre alt.

Comment: Solche „persönlichen Meinungen“ hast Du öfter, oder?

Comment: Wenn eine Erklärung unbefriedigend ist, suche ich nach  weiteren Möglickeiten. Und manchmal finde ich Erklärungen, die ich persönlich für plausibler halte. Jahrhundertflut macht Sinn, Immerflut macht keinen Sinn. Etymologische Lexika sind keine Bibeln mit unveränderlichen  Wahrheitem, sondern sind ständig auf ihre Plausibilität zu prüfen. Dazu haben wir zu viel Ungeklärtes oder nur Wahrscheinlich-Vermutungen in den Lexika. Aber , wie bereits gesagt,  wenn dir Immerflut als Deutung besser gefällt, ich habe nicht dagegen.

Comment: "singrüene" (immergrün) halte ich nicht gerade für eine überzeugende Erklärung für Sintflut.

Comment: Nach der Bearbeitung, in der du die "persönliche Meinung" ergänzt hast, gibt es von mir ein Downvote. So etwas gehört allenfalls in eine Antwort.

Comment: @rogermue: Meine Frage war nicht, ob cent für hundert ein gängiges Wort war, sondern das Reden von Jahrhundertflut, Jahrhunderttalent, Jahrhundertwinter usw. Und weiter noch: Hat man zur Zeit der Begriffsprägung überhaupt mit Jahrhunderten gerechnet?

Comment: @user unknown  Warum sollte ein Zeitraum von 100 Jahren im Ahd unbekannt sein?  Jahrhundert gibt es ja schon im Lateinischen, saeculum Menschenalter, Jahrhundert.

Comment: a) Ich weiß ja nicht welcher Begriff in den lateinischen Vorlagen verwendet wird oder in der hebräischen Thora. Orientiert sich der deutsche Begriff nicht in erster Linie daran? b) Sagte ich nicht, dass der Begriff unbekannt gewesen sei, sondern fragte ob Bildungen mit 'Jahrhundert' vorneweg üblich waren.

Comment: Die lateinische Vulgata spricht von diluvium. Das hebräische Wort ist mabu:l (himmlische Wasserkrüge).Es wäre allerdings interessant zu ermitteln, was die gotische Bibelübersetzung hat. Sintflut scheint eine Wortschöpfung des Ahd zu sein.

Comment: Wahrscheinlich nicht das "Sint" in Sintflut,  aber doch eine Entdeckung, die das Herz des Volksetymologen höher schlagen lässt: "'Hindi' comes from Persian hind, for the area of the Indus valley. [...] derived from Indo-Aryan sindhu meaning 'ocean' or 'river'. " Quelle: Blackwell Companion to Hinduism, p. 3

Answer (score 10):

Alle gedruckten Nachschlagewerke, die ich befragt habe (u. a. Mackensen, Etymologie), waren sich einig:

> mhd./ahd. *sin(t)vluot* aus *sin* = dauernd, gewaltig und *Flut*; die Form Sündflut beruht auf volksetymol. Umdeutung des unverständlich gewordenen ersten Wortteils.

*Dauernd* oder *gewaltig* passt ja sehr viel besser als *ewig*, den Hang zu Übertreibungen gab es wohl schon zu allen Zeiten.

Comment: @rogermue: *sin-* als Teil von Komposita ist sehr wohl in verschiedenen germanischen Sprachen belegt; sie werden bei Pfeifer (im DWDS) auch aufgeführt. Darunter sind auch Beispiele wie _sinhere_, in denen nicht die Bedeutung "ewig" auftaucht, die dich so stört. Ebenso sagt Pfeifer durchaus, woher seiner Ansicht nach das _t_ kommt (Gleitlaut zwischen _n_ und _f_).

Comment: Kobler, Ahd, sagt bei simbalig adj ewig, unaufhörlich unablässig, beständig. Er sagt nichts von groß oder gewaltig. Auch bei den anderen ähnlichen Varianten mit simb- kommt groß oder gewaltig nicht vor.

Comment: Wenn es vierzig Tage regnet bedarf es keiner großen Übertreibung, um zu sagen, dass es unablässig regnet.

Answer (score 0):

Hauptsächlich der von Dir genannten Quelle entnommen:

Das althochdeutsche Wort ist „sinfluot“, das *t* erscheint später, wohl aus Aussprachegründen. Die Vorsilbe „sin-“ ist verstärkend. Die von Dir erwähnte Verwandtschaft mit „semper“ ist wohl vorhanden, aber die Bedeutung des lateinischen Wortes ist unerheblich, wesentlich ist die Bedeutung im Germanischen. Für die Vorsilbe „sin-“ gibt es auch andere Beispiele, sie ist also nicht reine Spekulation, vergleiche auch [mit dem Altenglischen](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sin-#Old_English).

Wie Du selber andeutest, bräuchte man Klimmzüge, um von „cent“ auf „sint-“ und erst recht auf „sin-“ zu kommen. Es gibt keinen Anlass für diese. Ein weiteres Beispiel für die Lautverschiebung, der wir im Deutschen ein *h* zu verdanken haben, wo im Lateinischen ein *k*-Laut ist, ist übrigens *centum/hundert*.

Comment: Der ahd Stamm sim/simb- heißt wie lat. semper im Grunde "immer". Köbler, Ahd, führt führt 7 Varianten mit dem Stamm simb- und der Bedeutung immer auf. - Von  centum zu Sint sind keine Klimmzüge nötig.  Wir sprechen heute cent wie tsent aus und die Ähnlichkeit von tsent und sint dürfte nicht schwerfallen. Wir wissen nichts über den Weg von Sintflut, das kann über Italienisch, Spanisch,  Französisch gekommen sein, der normale hist. Lautwandel von Latein zu Ahd muß nicht unbedingt vorliegen.

Comment: Ich hatte gehofft, klar gemacht zu haben, dass es ein Fehler ist, das *t* in die Etymologie einfließen zu lassen.